# How to unmarshal json data to print in a well defined format

Tags: json, api, go, unmarshalling

I can't figure out how to unmarshal the json data provided by an api and consume the data to print in a specified format.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

type postOffice []struct {
    Name    string
    Taluk   string
    Region  string
    Country string
}

func main() {
    data, err := http.Get("http://postalpincode.in/api/pincode/221010")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("The http request has a error : %s", err)
    } else {
        read, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(data.Body)
        var po postOffice
        err = json.Unmarshal(read, &po)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%s", err)
        }
        fmt.Print(po)
    }

}
```

The code was working well till the "read" was evaluated but is throwing the following error on using json.Unmarshal "json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type main.post[]"

Comment: JSON objects must be unmarshalled into struct values or maps, but you have a slice value (which works with JSON arrays only).

Answer (score 2):

You need create a second struct to receive the whole JSON.

```
type JSONResponse struct {
    Message    string     `json:"Message"`
    Status     string     `json:"Success"`
    PostOffice postOffice `json:"PostOffice"`
}
```

This is because the `PostOffice` is an array inside of the response.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

//this is the new struct
type JSONResponse struct {
    Message    string     `json:"Message"`
    Status     string     `json:"Success"`
    PostOffice postOffice `json:"PostOffice"`
}

type postOffice []struct {
    Name    string
    Taluk   string
    Region  string
    Country string
}

func main() {
    data, err := http.Get("http://postalpincode.in/api/pincode/221010")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("The http request has a error : %s", err)
    } else {
        read, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(data.Body)
        //change the type of the struct
        var po JSONResponse
        err = json.Unmarshal(read, &po)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%s", err)
        }
        fmt.Print(po)
    }

}
```